# looping to summarize a column in R based on presence of certain strings/values in other column(s)

Tags: r, loops, summarize

R version 4.2.3

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

data<-structure(list(sequencing_id = c("N18-04248", "N18-04249", "N18-04249", 
"N18-04249", "N18-04249", "N18-04249", "N18-04251", "N18-04252", 
"N18-04252", "N18-04253", "N18-04253"), No_genes = c(0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 1, 0), rep_type.s. = c("rep_cluster_1778, IncQ1", 
"rep_cluster_2401", "rep_cluster_1778, IncQ1", "IncFIA,IncFIC,IncFII,Col156", 
"Col156", "Col.MG828", "Col.BS512", "IncQ1", "IncFIA,IncQ1", "IncFIC,rep_cluster_2244", 
"IncFIB,Col156"), Col156 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L), IncQ1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = 1:11, class =              "data.frame")
```

I actually have 49 different rep_types (only two are listed here as an example, but I have all of them listed as rep_types):

```
rep_types <- c("IncQ1”,"Col156")
```

I would like to accomplish three things with this data based on the information in column “rep_type.s.”. I use "IncQ1 as an example here, but my goal is to do this for all 49 rep_types in my list:

1. Summarize variable “No_genes” for all rows containing any instance of “IncQ1”
2. Summarize variable “No_genes” for all rows containing only the exact match of “IncQ1” alone (e.g., row 8)
3. Summarize variable “No_genes” for all rows containing only “IncQ1” when present with other rep types (e.g., row 9)

To accomplish the first objective I would write the following code for “IncQ1”:

```
Z<- data %>% filter(`IncQ`==1) 
summary(Z$No_genes)
```

As a relative beginner in R, I'm not sure how to pursue this. I've used a loop before, but not sure if this is the best approach here. I know that I can accomplish the first objective by creating subsets of the data based on filtering for the presence of the variables in columns captured by rep_types (would have to write out the above code 49 times....). I would prefer to filter the strings in column “rep_type.s.” to accomplish all three objectives most elegantly.

My attempts thus far are not coming close to accomplishing any of the objectives and generating error codes or just not doing at all what I'm hoping they will:

```
for(i in rep_types){X%>%
   filter(i==1)%>% summarize(X$No_genes) %>% print()
  }

data%>% filter(if_any(everything(), ~ grepl('IncQ', .)))) %>% summarize(No_genes)
```

Thanks in advance for any help or tips you can provide.

Edit:
Here's an example of the output I am looking for based on the modified data provided by @LeroyTyrone:

I didn't include the quartiles or median, but if they are produced as part of the "summary" that's fine. These are just the values I'm specifically interested in knowing. Thank you!

| gene | exact_min | exact_mean | exact_max | anyinst_min | anyinst_mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IncQ1 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 1 | 5.25 |
| Col156 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 6.67 |
| Col.BS512 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 |

| gene | anyinst_max | multireps_min | multireps_mean | multireps_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IncQ1 | 9 | 1 | 4.33 | 9 |
| Col156 | 11 | 4 | 9.5 | 11 |
| Col.BS512 | 7 | n/a | n/a | n/a |

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example data you provided, this should work. You didn't give an example of the output you wanted so I have created an arbitrary dataframe called "gene_sum" to hold the results. I have update the answer to reflect your comment.

Due to the number of 0s in your example, I've provided a modified version of your data in order to better illustrate that it works. I have also modified the list of "rep types" in order to produce a more illustrative result:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Modified version of your dataframe with different values for "No_genes" for illustrative purposes
data <- structure(list(sequencing_id = c("N18-04248", "N18-04249", "N18-04249", 
                                         "N18-04249", "N18-04249", "N18-04249", 
                                         "N18-04251", "N18-04252", "N18-04252", 
                                         "N18-04253", "N18-04253"), 
                       No_genes = 1:11, 
                       rep_type.s. = c("rep_cluster_1778, IncQ1", "rep_cluster_2401",
                                       "rep_cluster_1778, IncQ1", "IncFIA,IncFIC,IncFII,Col156",
                                       "Col156", "Col.MG828", "Col.BS512", "IncQ1", "IncFIA,IncQ1", 
                                       "IncFIC,rep_cluster_2244", "IncFIB,Col156"), 
                       Col156 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  1L), 
                       IncQ1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), 
                  row.names = 1:11, class = "data.frame")

rep_types <- c("IncQ1", "Col156", "IncFIA", "IncFIC", "Col.MG828", "IncFIB", "Col.BS512")

# Create empty dataframe to hold results
gene_sum <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 19))
colnames(gene_sum) <- c("gene",
                        paste0(rep(c("exact_", "anyinst_", "multireps_"), each = 6),
                               c("min", "q1st", "median", "mean", "q3rd", "max")))

for(i in rep_types) {
  
  # Return match criteria values
  tmp <- data %>%
    mutate(exact = ifelse(rep_type.s. == i, No_genes, 0),
           anyinst = ifelse(str_detect(rep_type.s., i) == TRUE, No_genes, 0),
           multireps = ifelse(str_count(data$rep_type.s., paste(rep_types, collapse='|')) > 1 &
                                str_detect(data$rep_type.s., i) == TRUE, No_genes, 0)) %>%
    select(exact:multireps)
  
  # Apply summary() function to all columns in tmp
  tmp <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(tmp, summary)), gene = i)
  # Get rownames into column (for identifying corresponding values)
  tmp$grouping <- rownames(tmp)
  # Change colnames() to "permitted" versions for the sake of simplicity
  colnames(tmp) <- c("min", "q1st", "median", "mean", "q3rd", "max", "gene", "grouping")
  
  # Get all summary data into a single row
  tmp <- tmp %>%
    pivot_longer(!c(gene, grouping),
                 names_to = "vars",
                 values_to = "value") %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = c(grouping, vars))
   
  # Add result to results df 
  gene_sum <- rbind(gene_sum, tmp)
  
}

# Please note that the colnames() and number of columns in the results 
# below have been truncated by R
gene_sum
# A tibble: 7 × 19
  gene      exact_min exact…¹ exact…² exact…³ exact…⁴ exact…⁵ anyin…⁶ anyin…⁷ anyin…⁸ anyin…⁹
  <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 IncQ1             0       0       0   0.727       0       8       0       0       0   1.91 
2 Col156            0       0       0   0.455       0       5       0       0       0   1.82 
3 IncFIA            0       0       0   0           0       0       0       0       0   1.18 
4 IncFIC            0       0       0   0           0       0       0       0       0   1.27 
5 Col.MG828         0       0       0   0.545       0       6       0       0       0   0.545
6 IncFIB            0       0       0   0           0       0       0       0       0   1    
7 Col.BS512         0       0       0   0.636       0       7       0       0       0   0.636

# Result from your original example data
# A tibble: 7 × 19
  gene      exact_min exact…¹ exact…² exact…³ exact…⁴ exact…⁵ anyin…⁶ anyin…⁷ anyin…⁸ anyin…⁹
  <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 IncQ1             0       0       0   0.545       0       6       0       0       0   0.545
2 Col156            0       0       0   0           0       0       0       0       0   0.182
3 IncFIA            0       0       0   0           0       0       0       0       0   0.182
4 IncFIC            0       0       0   0           0       0       0       0       0   0.273
5 Col.MG828         0       0       0   0           0       0       0       0       0   0    
6 IncFIB            0       0       0   0           0       0       0       0       0   0    
7 Col.BS512         0       0       0   0.455       0       5       0       0       0   0.455
```

Comment: I'd like to clarify briefly that I need the mean number of genes and the range for each column in gene_sum (as would be provided by "summary" not "summarize"--my error in the original question). I tried substituting "mean" or "range" instead of "sum" just after "summarise_at", but no luck. I suspect the earlier code may need to be modified? Thanks very much for your help with this.

Comment: @NadineVogt - I have updated the answer to reflect your comment. I have also annotated some sections so you can better see what the code is doing.

Comment: Thanks for annotating the code---helps me learn! I noticed that the output is summarizing over all of the rows for each column, but the summary I am looking for is just for the rows where the instance of exact, multireps, or anyinstance was present (so in the example dataset we are looking at these would be the rows with numbers in them, because none of the rows had 0 genes in them). Is there a way to accomplish this without selecting only those rows and running each column (i.e., exact, multireps, anyinstance) as a separate dataset?

Comment: Also---when I looked at the multireps column for IncQ1 it didn't pick up all of the instances of multireps but I don't know why!? Thanks again.

Comment: 1) It is still not quite clear what you mean, it would be great if you could edit your question to clarify exactly what you want and also add a desired output example.

Comment: 2) I just checked and multireps is finding every instance where more than one value from "rep_types" is present. If every instance of multiple "rep_types" is not being found, it's most likely because not every rep type is in the "rep_types" list. You can confirm this by adding every rep type to your "rep_types" list and running the loop again.

Answer (score 0):

If I change the middle part of the code to "NA" instead of "0":

```
  tmp <- data %>%
mutate(exact = ifelse(rep_type.s. == i, No_genes, NA),
       anyinst = ifelse(str_detect(rep_type.s., i) == TRUE, No_genes, NA),
       multireps = ifelse(str_count(data$rep_type.s., paste(rep_types, collapse='|')) > 1 &
                            str_detect(data$rep_type.s., i) == TRUE, No_genes, NA)) %>%
select(exact:multireps)
```

I am able to get the correct values for the "exact" and "anyinst" columns. For some reason the "multireps" isn't matching up to my expected output...

The dataframe at the end doesn't load with the change to "NA". This is the error message I get:

Error in `[.data.frame`(data, unique(names(data))) :
undefined columns selected